# Confusion Matrix in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression

In Logistic Regression for binary classification, while using `predict()`, how does the classifier decide for the class (1/0)?

Is it based on the probability threshold, if >0.5 then 1 else 0? If so, can this threshold be manually changed?

I know we get probabilities from `predict_prob()`, but i was curious about `predict()` function!

Comment: It picks the class with the highest probability.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic Regression, like other classification models, returns a probability for each class. Being a binary predictor, it has only two classes.

From the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L311), `predict()` returns the class with the highest class probability.

```
def predict(self, X):
    """Predict class labels for samples in X.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
        Samples.
    Returns
    -------
    C : array, shape = [n_samples]
        Predicted class label per sample.
    """
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
    if len(scores.shape) == 1:
        indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)
    else:
        indices = scores.argmax(axis=1)
    return self.classes_[indices]
```

So yes, in this case it returns the class with a probability greater than 50%, since the sum of the class probabilities = 1.

Comment: Okay, Thanks.
So where does maximum likelihood estimation come into picture?
I'm sorry, if its totally unrelated to it.

Comment: That's a question better suited to Math Overflow. Here's the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Maximum_likelihood_estimation).

Comment: MLE is relevant in trying to calculate the coefficients of the model, based on some trained data. Predictions are then made on new data, using the model coefficients.